# Why would js behave different when the Chrome Inspector is open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**EDIT**: I was able to solve this by changing `$.removeAttr('style')` to `attr('style','')`. But never discovered why it was happening in the first place.

---

I am having an issue with a script where a box is supposed to disappear and become unstyled when I click off of it, and when a certain target element is clicked again it gets the offset from the clicked item.

What's happening though is odd... when I click the item and click off then click back, the element moves down and to the right, and does so consistently (each time it appears a little down and to the right). I thought perhaps the style wasn't being properly removed so I opened up the Inspector to investigate its properties. However with the inspector open everything works perfectly.  It works fine in Firefox and IE as well, but not Safari.

I will include some of the code, but my main concern is how there could be a difference in behaviour with the Chrome Inspector open vs closed

```
$('body').click(function(event) {        
    if (imageUpload){
        commitUpload(imageUpload);
    }
});

$('#logo1, #logo2').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var num = (this.id).substr((this.id).length-1, 1);

    if (imageUpload && imageUpload != num){
        commitUpload(imageUpload);

    imageUpload = num;
    $('#upload_logo'+num)
        .offset($(this).offset())
        .show();
 });

function commitUpload(obj){
    if (obj < 3){
        $('#upload_logo'+obj).removeAttr('style').css('display', 'none').css('position', 'absolute');
        if ($('#urlEdit').is(':visible')){
        $('#form_logo'+obj+'_url').val($('#urlEdit').val());
            }
    }
    imageUpload = null;
}
```

Comment: Shot in the dark to rule out a simple case - do you have the inspector opening as a separate window or is it a frame within the browser window?  If it's the latter and any of your positioning, widths or heights are relative to the viewport, that might be a factor...

Comment: separate window...  i fixed the problem by changing `removeAttrib('style')` to `atrrib('style','')`, but still weirded out be the oddness in interpretation. beginning to think a bug related to removeAttrib in jquery

Comment: Interesting, good to know.  Glad you got it solved!

Comment: hate solutions that still leave questions, though ;)